# php how to find from which place SESSION change?

Tags: php, session

I have 4 SESSION variables for keeping a user active

```
                    $_SESSION['login']
                    $_SESSION['m_ID'] 
                    $_SESSION['l_cd'] 
                    $_SESSION['loginAs']
```

When I visit to another profile from my profile I automatically log out, because `$_SESSION['m_ID']` changes to profile of the id I visit. I only change `$_SESSION['m_ID']` when logging in. There are three type of login.

1. normal user
2. admin
3. cookie(if u put remember me, after u close the
       browser and reopen it automatically set session from cookies )

I searched the entire site for `$_SESSION['m_ID'] =` and '`$_SESSION["m_ID"]=`' but I only found these three. On my local site it works fine. Is there anyway to fine where the session is change ?

Comment: or you could just look for `$_SESSION` without any keys, in case youv'e got some code that does stuff like `$_SESSION = array()`.

Comment: there are lot, 354 found :D

Comment: There can be any number of reasons for your problem. Without being able to view your code, it's very hard (impossible) to know what's causing the problem. If it works locally, but not on your server, it could even be a problem completely outside of your code. Something with the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

PHP store in your browser a cookie with the reference of the phisically serialized file of the session data.

When you call session_destroy() or similar this cookie expire. After logout, when you call session_start() a new cookie is created with the reference of another file.

You need to unset all variables because you don't refresh the session, the cookie is the same all time. I recomend to you to use sesion_destroy() to logout.